# "joins" with two tables does not work because of "ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing my application on Ruby-on-Rails and I have a problem with "joins". There are 3 tables: `todo_lists`, `users`, `statuses`. Each todo has one user and one status and they are introduced as IDs. And I want to get the whole todo with status name and user name instead of their IDs. This is how I tried to do that:

```
TodoList.joins(:user, :status)
  .select("
  todo_lists.id,
  todo_lists.title,
  todo_lists.description,
  statuses.name,
  users.name,
  todo_lists.deadline,
  todo_lists.is_disabled")
.as_json
```

But this throws an MissingAttribute error: `missing attribute: status_id`. But I added `user_id` and `status_id` records to my `todo_lists` table before that. What I must to do to solve this?

`user.rb`, `status.rb`, `todo_list.rb` files:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :todo_lists
end

class Status < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todo_lists
end

class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :status
    belongs_to :user
end
```

`schema.rb` file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_03_17_071204) do

  create_table "statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "todo_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", default: 1, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "is_disabled"
    t.datetime "deadline"
    t.string "title", null: false
    t.integer "status_id", default: 1, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "todo_lists", "statuses"
  add_foreign_key "todo_lists", "users"
end
```

The most interesting is that if I joins with only `users` table, everything works fine :)
The full stack trace:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (missing attribute: status_id):

app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:75:in `get_all_todos'
app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:3:in `get'
```

And `todos_controller.rb` methods where I am using "joins":

```
def get
    render :json => get_all_todos
end

def get_all_todos
    TodoList.joins(:status, :user)
    .select("
         todo_lists.id,
         todo_lists.title,
         todo_lists.description,
         statuses.status,
         todo_lists.deadline,
         todo_lists.is_disabled")
    .as_json
end
```

Comment: Please post the full error message including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are performed `on` a `related` column between two or more tables.

In the configuration that you have given, you are trying to join todo_lists to users and statuses table, but there is no relationship column to join `on`.

At the same time, the reason todo_lists join with users works because the join is performed on `user_id` column of todo_lists.

`ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError` is raised because it cannot find this related column to join these two tables with, I am not sure about your applications specific domain logic, but you can fix this by adding `user_id` [foreign_key](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/04/foreign-key-in-dbms/) to todo_lists table.

Comment: I have already added `status_id` and `user_id` columns to `todo_lists` table ang gave `foreign_keys` to tables. I met this error when I tried to join `users` and `todo_lists` tables and the problem was I added column `assigned_user_id` column instead of `user_id`.